# Update the data in the selected row

Tags: c#

Can't update the data in the selected row. The data is updated throughout the table. I ask for help!

```
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\mydb.accdb";

Connecton();
string sql = "UPDATE tablename SET name = txtName, fam = txtFam";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fam", txtFam.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Success", "Add", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
ShowDataDictionary();
ConClose();
```

Comment: You don't apply any `WHERE` condition so it will update all records.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `where` keyword.

it is also required to use `@`

### your code will be like this

```
string sql = "UPDATE tablename SET name = @Name, fam = @txtFam where Id = @Id";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fam", txtFam.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", txtFam.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks! Error in the line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue (" Id ", txtFam.Id);` (`txtFam.Id` Underlined by a wavy line)